# Regex does not match for exact pattern

Tags: regex, qt

I would like to match only the following pattern:

```
/a
/b
/c
```

and others should return false:

```
/a/foo
/bX
/c23
```

etc.

For this I have the following code:

```
QRegExp navigation("^/(a|b|c)\b");
```

However `navigation.indexIn(str)` returns `-1`

How should I modify the code so that this returns a positive value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried:

```
^/(a|b|c)$
```

---

With this regex engine you need to change it to:

```
/^\/(a|b|c)$/gm
```

---

As Spidey wrote also this works:

```
/^\/[abc]$/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure nut I think you have to double escape the word boundary:

```
QRegExp navigation("^/(a|b|c)\\b");
```